# How do I get a sequential number in a file name?

Tags: php, csv

The below code works nicely to copy and rename file with date variable in, but now I have to add a sequential number to the **???** in GRPROMO_0000_".$date->format('Ymd-His'). "-**???**.READY. Is this at all possible while the date is also changing?

At the end the file should look something like this GRPROMO_0000_20210910-155301-145.READY

Thank you in advance for the assist...

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

$file = '/var/www/html/stock/BRNCH0.csv';
$newfile = '/var/www/html/stock/csvs/BRNCH0.csv';
$file2 = '/var/www/html/stock/csvs/BRNCH0.csv';
if(!copy($file, $newfile)){
    echo "failed to copy $file";
}
else{
    echo "copied $file into $newfile\n";
    rename($file2 , "/var/www/html/stock/csvs/GRPROMO_0000_".$date->format('Ymd-His'). "-???.READY");
}
?>
```

I have updated my code. It's works with file that does not have the date in or the date is the same **GRPROMO_0000_20210913-094044-01.csv GRPROMO_0000_20210913-094044-02.csv**.
But with the date that changes my code thinks it's a **new** file and does not increment it correctly **GRPROMO_0000_20210913-100457-01.READY
GRPROMO_0000_20210913-100734-01.READY GRPROMO_0000_20210913-101015-01.READY**. Please help.
Thank you

```
<?php
$file = '/var/www/html/stock/BRNCH0.csv'; //orignal file
$newfile = '/var/www/html/stock/csvs/BRNCH0.csv'; //copy orignal file to this Dir
$date = new DateTime();
$dir1 = '/var/www/html/stock/csvs/'; // read folder name 
$dir2 = '/var/www/html/stock/csc/'; // move to folder name
if(!copy($file, $newfile)){
    echo "failed to copy $file";
}
else{
    echo "copied $file into $newfile\n";
}
$filearr = scandir ($dir1); // read folder
Unset ($filearr [0]); // remove redundant elements
unset($filearr[1]);
$filearr = array_values ($filearr); // start the array from 0 and increment it by 1
$filecount = count ($filearr); // number of files
$onenum = 1; // start number
$maxnum = $onenum + $filecount; // max cycles
$title ="GRPROMO_0000_".$date->format('Ymd-His')."-"; // file title
$ext = '.READY'; // file suffix
for ($i = $onenum; $i <= $maxnum; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j < $filecount ; $j++) {
        if($i<10){
            $i = '0'.$i;
        }
        rename($dir1.$filearr[$j],$dir2.$title.$i.$ext);
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: use a loop that increments a counter variable, appends it to the filename, and checks if the file exists. When you find a number that doesn't exist, use that filename.

Comment: Any other Ideas?